# Jquery issues with string as parameter

Tags: jquery, function, parameters, odata

I have a jquery code where I am calling a string as parameter and using it in side the function. but it is taking parameter as integer.

```
function CheckIsApplicable(MsNo) {
            var queryUrl = 'GroupEntity?$filter=(MSNumber eq ' +  MsNo + ')';
    }
```

MsNo is a string and the way the odata url considers it is a integer. It throws a bad request error if I call this function. How can I call a string in the filter? I tried '"+ MsNo +"' and it failed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
MsNo.toString();
```

here:

```
function CheckIsApplicable(MsNo) {
        var queryUrl = "GroupEntity?$filter=(MSNumber eq '" + MsNo.toString() + "')"; 
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to get '' single quotes on MsNo instead of converting to string. Any idea?

Comment: yes, try this  var queryUrl = "GroupEntity?$filter=(MSNumber eq '" +  MsNo.toString() + "')";